# Kendo widgets- appearing twice

Tags: kendo-ui, angular-kendo

I have included a simple kendo dropdown control in html5 page. I have used angular in my project.

The html code looks like:

```
<select id="locationsDropdown" kendo-drop-down-list>
                            <option>All Locations</option>
                            <option>Data 1</option>
                            <option>Data 2</option>
                            <option>Data 3</option>
                        </select>
```

The dropdown appears twice in the view. I have this problem with other kendo widgets as well. Can anyone help me solving this issue?
Here is the image of how the dropdown looks in my application: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=jl6suf&s=8#.U58AzSg30iQ

There are two dropdowns as shown in the image.

Thanks.

Comment: This uses to happen when you initialize (accidentally) the widget twice. Could you create a JSFiddle/JSBin that reproduces it?

Comment: i am not able to replicate the same here: http://jsfiddle.net/7NMmm/3/     is there any other way i can avoid widget initialization twicE?

Comment: :-( If your code is actually initializing it twice the question if finding out how / where. Any other _solution_ will have side effects (seeing the widget twice is just the tip of the iceberg). Did you try setting a breakpoint in the browser debugger where your initialize it and see if it is being invoked twice?

Comment: No, not able to solve it.

Comment: Have same issue, Anyone any progress?

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly the same issue and found that I had some leftover CSS styling on the "select" in a stylesheet included AFTER the Kendo stylesheets, the offending style was as follows.

```
select {
display: inline-block !important;
}
```

with this removed the additional control disappeared.

Hope this helps.